If I rewrite someone's Scratch game in Python, am I required to disclose the source code? Can I sell it?
The license for all projects shared at the Scratch Website is the Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license 2.0. I would have to credit the author and share under the same license, but it is unspecified whether I need to disclose the source code or not. I'm also unsure as to whether or not this counts as a derivative work, since I'm essentially rewriting the game in a different programming language for a different platform with a different game engine, as opposed to simply packaging it with Electron and calling it a day, which would mean I'm only copying their algorithm, not the actual code itself. Do I need to include the source code when distributing my game? Also, can I sell my game under the required CC BY-SA license, so users are free to share the game amongst themselves, but if they want to download it from my "official" source, they would have to pay me?


I'm also unsure as to whether or not this counts as a derivative work, since I'm essentially rewriting the game in a different programming language

One of the rights granted by copyright is the right to control the publication of translations, so yes, your translation is absolutely a derivative work.

it is unspecified whether I need to disclose the source code or not

Which is why the CC licences are not recommended for software.  I'm no programmer, but my understanding of Python is that it's an interpreted language, so providing the source code is part of providing the game.  If, however, you are somehow compiling it into an executable, then I can't see any reason why you should have to provide source.

can I sell my game under the required CC BY-SA license

Yes, you may, and you seem to have understood perfectly the consequences of that.

Ok, I understand. I am planning on using pyinstaller to package it as an .exe. Thanks for the information.
